# Play Games Sign in does not work after publishing it in play store but it was working when i tested on my android device from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, google-play-games, google-workspace

Play games sign in is not working in my app after i published it. I am unable to understant what is the problem
These are the functions created for signingin and for achievements and leaderboard.I think problem is related to OAuth Server but i dont know how to do it.Can Somone Explain it.

```
private fun startSignInIntent() {
    val signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
    val intent = signInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN)
}
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
        if (result!!.isSuccess) {
            mServerAuthCode = result.signInAccount!!.serverAuthCode
            // The signed in account is stored in the result.
            val signedInAccount = result.signInAccount
        } else {
            var message = result.status.statusMessage
            if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                message = getString(R.string.signin_other_error)
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show()
        }
    }
}
private fun showAchievements() {
    Games.getAchievementsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)!!)
        .achievementsIntent
        .addOnSuccessListener { intent -> startActivityForResult(intent, RC_ACHIEVEMENT_UI) }
}
private val RC_LEADERBOARD_UI = 9004
private fun showLeaderboard() {
    Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)!!)
        .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_marathon))
        .addOnSuccessListener { intent -> startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI) }
}
private fun showLeaderboard2() {
    Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)!!)
        .getLeaderboardIntent(getString(R.string.leaderboard_timer_mode))
        .addOnSuccessListener { intent -> startActivityForResult(intent, RC_LEADERBOARD_UI) }
}
private fun signOut() {
    val signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
            GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
    signInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this
    ) {
        // at this point, the user is signed out.
    }
}
private fun signInSilently() {
    val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN
    val account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)
    if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, *signInOptions.scopeArray)) {
        // Already signed in.
        // The signed in account is stored in the 'account' variable.
        val signedInAccount = account
    } else {
        // Haven't been signed-in before. Try the silent sign-in first.
        val signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions)
        signInClient
                .silentSignIn()
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        this
                ) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val signedInAccount = task.result
            
                }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you publish the app on Play Store, Google signs it and the Google app signing key certificate needs to be registered in the project's Firebase console for it to work. After you publish the app, in the Play Console, under Release, click on Settings. Click on App Integrity. Click on the App Signing tab. Copy the SHA-1 fingerprint to your clipboard. Go to your Firebase Console and select your project. To the right of Project Overview, click the gear icon and select Project Settings. Under Your Apps, click on your Android app and enter the SHA-1 fingerprint that you copied from the App Signing tab.